# Getting segmentation fault(core dumped) after installing glibc through conda

Tags: python, centos, glibc, rhel

I am trying to install glibc through conda on `CentOS - 6.5` using

`conda install -c dan_blanchard glibc`
It installs glibc-2.18.
I am getting `Getting segmentation fault(core dumped)` after running the above command when I try to open the python in terminal.

I am working on a remote server with no admin privileges.
On running `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` , I am getting 
`/share/opt/python/3.6.5/lib:/share/lsf/9.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/lib`

I need to update Glibc for installing `pytorch=1.3` from [source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#get-the-pytorch-source) .
Is it possible to update glibc?
If yes, then what I can do to make it right?
I checked the below answer also but couldn't apply to my use-case as it have root privileges.

[After updating glibc: Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566601/after-updating-glibc-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never touch a distribution's included `glibc` library. Not unless you are the sort of expert that can debug and fix the issues that then happen.

`glibc` is the standard system C library. It's the library every single application uses. If there's any change in the what the API looks like, or a change in the implementation of the C standard library - any corner case, any change to run time performance - it can break any number of applications, if not your entire system. That's an extremely risky thing to do.

If you want a newer `glibc`, switch to a more recent distribution - probably a newer version of RHEL in your case.